# Integral formulation of the Cauchy problem

Tags: calculus

Let be $\delta>0$, these two propositions are equivalent:

1) there exists $x$ continuous and derivable in $[t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta]$ such that:
$x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$ and $x(t_0)=x_0$

$\iff$

2) there exists $x$ continuous in $[t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta]$ such that:
$x(t)= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s,x(s))ds$

How do I use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that $x$ is derivable and its derivative is $f(t,x(t))$ in the $\Leftarrow$ implication?

PS: sorry for my english!

Comment: Initially $x'(t)=\dots$, under the integral $f(s,x(s))$ and at the end $f(t,x(t))$.

Comment: Of course $f$ is supposed continuous (as a function of two variables). The key fact is that, if $x(t)$ is continuous, then $f(t,x(t))$ is continuous (as a function of one variable); so, applying the FTC, $\dots$